# Binding a non-const lvalue reference to a deduced non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, non-type-template-parameter

Consider a function template `f` that binds a non-const lvalue reference to a deduced non-type template parameter

```
template <auto N> 
void f()
{
    auto & n = N;
}
```

This works when `f` is instantiated over class types

```
struct S {};
f<S{}>();    // ok
```

But doesn't work when instantiated over non class types (as I expected)

```
f<42>();  // error non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'int'
```

The same error is emitted if an lvalue argument is used to instantiate `f` as well

```
constexpr int i = 42;
f<i>();                // also error
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MafKo4WWr) to play with.

This looks like non-type template parameters of class type are lvalues, which seems odd. Where does the standard make a distinction between these kinds of instantiations, and why is there a difference if the argument to the template is of class type?

Comment: Hmm... Isn't this the same as  `int main() { auto& n = 42; }` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, it is, which is why I'm not surprised with the error. It's the fact that using `S` does work that I'm confused by, since `int main() { auto & n = S{}; }` is also an error https://godbolt.org/z/4sWdovqnM

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood :)

Comment: _Where does the standard make a distinction between these kinds of instantiations_ https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.unqual#2.sentence-7 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#def:template_parameter_object

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Ah, that appears to be what I'm looking for, thanks. Do you want to go ahead and write it up as an answer?

Comment: _Do you want to go ahead and write it up as an answer?_ No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the distinction is because class non-type template parameters weren't always there. Originally, value template parameters could only be pointers, integers, or a few other things. Such parameters were simple and the value was just a single number known at compile-time. As such, making them rvalues (remember: prvalue is C++11) was OK.

Once NTTPs could be more complex object types, you have to start engaging with certain questions. Should you be able to do this:

```
template<std::array<int, 5> arr>
void func()
{
  for(int i: arr)
    //stuff
}
```

The obvious answer is "of course you should." But that would require that you can get a reference to `arr` itself. That's how range-based `for` is defined, after all.

Now that can still work. After all, range-based `for` uses `auto&&` to store its reference, so it can reference a prvalue. But that has consequences.

Namely, if you create a reference to a prvalue, that causes the materialization of a temporary. A *new* temporary object distinct from all other objects.

This means that if you use a class NTTP in multiple places, you will get different objects with different addresses and different addresses for their subobjects. And this is something you can *detect*, since you can get the addresses of their subobjects.

Forcing compile-time code to create temporaries every time you use the name is bad for performance. So two different uses of such a parameter need to result in talking about the same object.

Therefore, class NTTPs need to be lvalues; each use of the name within a template is referring to the same object. But you can't go back and make all existing NTTPs lvalues too; that would break existing code.

So that's where we are.

As for where this is defined, it is in [[temp.param]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#8):

> An id-expression naming a non-type template-parameter of class type `T` denotes a static storage duration object of type `const T`, known as a template parameter object, whose value is that of the corresponding template argument after it has been converted to the type of the template-parameter. All such template parameters in the program of the same type with the same value denote the same template parameter object.

Comment: Minor clarification: the text says "`T` denotes ... of type `const T`", but the type doesn't appear to be `const`, i.e. a non-const lvalue reference can also be bound to it. Am I reading the `const` part incorrectly?

Comment: @cigien: If an object is `const`, then `auto` will deduce it as `const`.

Comment: Oh, of course. I ran it through cppinsights to see the instantiation, but I should have worked it out anyway. Thank you.